# Makefile - set environment variables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to set an environment variables(service and index) in Ubuntu as mentioned in other posts but when I run echo $service, it wont return anything.

```
environment:
   @service=travelling \
   index=ficco
.PHONY: environment
```

$make environment 
$echo $service

Any suggestions??

Comment: You can't do that. Environment variables belong to a process, and can be inherited by a child process. Your shell runs make as a child process, that child process cannot set variables in its parent process (the shell) - it can only set its own environment variables and any child could inherit them again. . What do you really need to accomplish, and what do you need the makefile for ?

Comment: I want to set an environment variable on a Ubuntu machine so I can read that value from a java application.

Comment: Write the value into a file and read this file into java. Why don't you run the java from `Makefile`?

Comment: @raghzz Can you create a shell script that 1. sets the environment variables you need to, 2. starts your java application  ? Or do you have some other problem that makes that not possible ?